# partial request blob video javascript blob url

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, buffer, blob

i am trying to play a bufferd video by blob, but i had a problem with the buffer, when i give a blob url to video dom, the buffer set as full, but it's not, so how can i manage the buffer system for these type of videos.

some of code are below of my project.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/GV4d6/1/
```

codes are:

```
<video width=500 heigth=400 controls id='myvideo'></video>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");

xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.auby.no/files/video_tests/h264_720p_mp_3.1_3mbps_aac_shrinkage.mp4', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0-2000000")
xhr.send(null);


 var blobVideo = new Blob();

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
 var arrayBuffer = this.response;

 if (this.readyState>3) {



    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    blobVideo = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "text" });

    var url = window.URL = window.webkitURL;

    videoUrl = url.createObjectURL(blobVideo);
    video.src = videoUrl;
      }
   }
    </script>
```